# Wrapping OpenSCAD code in module breaks code

Tags: openscad

My problem is simple: I have code that renders what I want, but when I put it into a module, OpenSCAD throws an error when I render saying that no top level object was found.

```
    difference()
    {
        flipper(length, res, chord, xlambda, xA, ylambda, yA, phase);
        //dye channels
        dye_channel(len_dye_1, loc_dye_1, chord, xlambda, xA, ylambda, dye_r_1);
        dye_channel(len_dye_2, loc_dye_2, chord, xlambda, xA, ylambda, dye_r_2);
        //dye_outlet
        translate([0,0,len_dye_1*floor(xlambda*chord)]) rotate([0,90,0]) cylinder(r=dye_r_1,h=loc_dye_1,$fn=25);
        translate([0,0,len_dye_2*floor(xlambda*chord)]) rotate([0,90,0]) cylinder(r=dye_r_2,h=loc_dye_2,$fn=25);
        //screw holes
        translate([loc_screw_1,0,0]) cylinder(r=screw_r_1,h=len_screw_1);
        translate([loc_screw_2,0,0]) cylinder(r=screw_r_2,h=len_screw_2);
    }
```

When I put this into a module, I get the error.

```
    module dye_flipper(len_dye_1, len_dye_2, loc_dye_1, loc_dye_2, len_screw_1, dye_r_1,
    dye_r_2, len_screw_2, loc_screw_1, loc_screw_2, screw_r_1, screw_r_2, length, res, 
    chord, xlambda, xA, ylambda, yA, phase)
    {...}
```

The functions of the other routines are a little complicated, and I imagine we could treat them as a black box. Just the difference code itself produces the object I want. I would like to put it into a module because that seems like good programming practice to me.

Comment: I get the same thing when I render this as a module or not. However, I don't have those extra modules. The only thing I see that could cause the problem is that you have a variable named `length` which is an internal openscad function name. You could try renaming that and see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds simple… but are you actually calling the module after defining it?
dye_flipper(…)